# Create Custom Back button in UINavigation bar in ios 8

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I need to customise the back button of UINavigationBar. To handle this I subclassed UINavigationController and wrote the following piece of code, which results in two arrow side by side:

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController
  willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
                animated:(BOOL)animated {
    UIBarButtonItem *backItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@""
                                                           style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                          target:nil
                                                          action:nil];
    [backItem setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:kBackButton]];
    [backItem setImageInsets:UIEdgeInsetsFromString(kImageInset)];
    viewController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backItem;
 }
```

In this code the arrow shifts its position when the action sheet shows up.

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController
  willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
                animated:(BOOL)animated {
    UIBarButtonItem *backItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@""
                                                           style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                          target:self
                                                          action:@selector(popViewControllerAnimated:)];

    [backItem setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:kBackButton]];
    [backItem setImageInsets:UIEdgeInsetsFromString(kImageInset)];
    viewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backItem;
 }
```

What would be the best approach to create back button where:

1. The arrow does not shift when action sheet shows up.
2. Two arrows are side by side.

Comment: @user3007060 could you clarify what you are actually asking for?

Comment: I explained the problems in both the approaches. I need to whether I am doing anything wrong? Or whether there is good approach to solve the issue.

Comment: Right what is the issue? "Creating a back Button"? "The arrow shifting up the sheet"? "Customizing the back button"? "Having arrows show up side by side"? You ask "What should be the best approach to do that?" It's unclear what "that" is.

Comment: Creating back button without having the following side effects.       1. The arrow should not shift while the action sheet show up      2. There shouldn't be two arrows side by side.

Comment: We're getting closer, what do you mean by "the following side effects"? "Two arrows side by side"? "The arrow shifting up the sheet"? Perhaps an explanation of what you want would be helpful.

Comment: Yes I want to create the button in such a way that the issues "Two arrows side by side" and "The arrow shifting up the sheet" shouldn't occur.

Comment: Thank you for editing. I think it is now clear what you're asking. I sadly don't know the solution for this but I'm sure someone here does. To increase exposure to knowledgeable people consider adding more relevant tags, for example this is ObjectiveC right? So I'd definitely add that tag.